# How to ignore apostrophes in html tag?

Tags: html, ruby

I'm sure someone will mark this as a duplicate question but no other answers worked for me.

I am using ruby and passing a variable into my html page. Let's say my variable "camp_name" is equal to "abc'd"

```
 <%=camp_name%>
```

This outputs  "abc'd" which is what I want.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_name" required value='<%=camp_name%>'>
```

The value in the field is now "abc" because of the single apostrophe. How do i get it to ignore apostrophes? Thanks.

Comment: Learn about escaping.

Comment: It's worse than you think. Never mind apostrophes - what happens if someone puts in `xxx'><script type='text/javascript'>alert("You've been hacked!");</script>` ?

Comment: This value needs to be HTML escaped.

Comment: If you're sure someone will mark it as a duplicate then you probably shouldn't ask it, or, you should show where you searched and explain why those didn't help, which helps us help you by reducing the number of places we have to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the variable to html entities:

```
camp_name.gsub("'", "&apos;")
```

You should do that for other characters as well, because, as mentioned by a comment, the user could simply insert an HTML tag in your page with your current script. Probably the most important ones are the following:

```
camp_name.gsub("<", "&lt;")
camp_name.gsub(">", "&gt;")
```

Comment: No problem :) @athill16

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rack (which would definitely be in use if you're using Rails or Sinatra, and it might be there even if you're not), there is a builtin for escaping HTML for just this kind of thing. Calling [`Rack::Utils#escape_html`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Utils#escape_html-class_method) will replace ampersands, brackets, and quotes with their HTML entities (e.g. `&apos;` instead of `'`).

In your case, you'd want the following code:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_name" required value='<%= Rack::Utils.escape_html(camp_name) %>'>
```

This would evaluate to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_name" required value='abc&apos;d'>
```

which is the proper way of displaying an apostrophe in HTML.

Just as a side note, displaying user-submitted text without escaping on a website is a *very* bad idea, because malicious users can add arbitrary Javascript that could render your site useless, add advertisements, and more. You should definitely get into the habit of escaping any text that users can submit before displaying it, either by `gsub`ing manually or using a helper method like this.